# When is the tensor unit a generator?

Tags: monoidal-categories

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a monoidal category with the tensor unit $I$. Then there is a "forgetful" functor from it to $Sets$:
\begin{equation}
  \mathrm{Hom}(I,-).
\end{equation}
But in general, this functor is actually not a forgetful functor as it may not be faithful.

My question is

> Is there any meaningful condition making the above functor faithful?

Comment: I don't think there's anything useful to say at this level of generality. The monoidal unit might as well be an arbitrary object in the category. "The unit is a generator" is the kind of thing that appears as a condition in other results, not the other way around.

Comment: Let me just give two classes of examples. On the one hand, if $C = \text{Mod}(k)$ for $k$ a commutative ring, the unit is always faithful. On the other hand, if $C = \text{Rep}(G)$ for $G$ a group, the unit is faithful iff $G$ is trivial.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks for your example.